# How to Line Break Emails that are created with Soap Request in CRM

Tags: javascript, email, crm

Hy Guys,

I'm trying a couple of hours to format an email that is created with JavaScript an Soap Request. But it won't work to set up line breaks

`\n` - doesn't work
`<br />` - doesn't work
`&#xD`; - doesn't work
`\u000A \u000D` - doesn't work

Here is my actual code for the email body

```
    get_EmailBodyInformManager: function (projectNumber, topic, responsibleDepartment, potentialCustomer, KAMofCustomer, projectManager) {
    if (KAMofCustomer == null) {
        KAMofCustomer = "";
    }
    return "Dear Sir or Madam. &#xD;" +
           "A decision about the project leader for the following international project is necessary: &#xD" +
           "Project Number: " + projectNumber + "&#xD;" +
           "Topic: " + topic + " &#xD;" +
           "Responsible Department: " + responsibleDepartment + "&#xD;" +
           "Potential Customer: " + potentialCustomer + "&#xD;" +
           "KAM of Potential Customer: " + KAMofCustomer + "&#xD;" +
           "WILO Project Manager: " + projectManager + "";
},
```

And the Soap Request:

```
        var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
          "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'" +
          " xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'" +
          " xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>" +
          authenticationHeader +
          "<soap:Body>" +
          "<Create xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'>" +
          "<entity xsi:type='email'>" +
          "<ownerid>" + userId + "</ownerid>" +
          "<regardingobjectid type='opportunity'>" + OpportunityId + "</regardingobjectid>" +
          "<subject>" + subject + "</subject>" +
          "<description>" + body + "</description>" +
          "<from>" +
            "<activityparty>" +
                "<partyid type='systemuser'>" + userId + "</partyid>" +
            "</activityparty>" +
          "</from>" +
          "</entity>" +
          "</Create>" +
          "</soap:Body>" +
          "</soap:Envelope>";
```

Comment: have you tried `+ "<br/>" +` in SOAP request part code?

Comment: Yes I had tried that. The strange thing, is that <br/> cuts the text, that comes after the <br/> tag.

Comment: If i write it directly into the SOAP Request, an Error Message came with "Email entity does not contain an element with "br"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should accept HTML format so long as what you pass through the description field is encoded for XML.  For the data you are looking to pass I would recommend formatting it as an HTML table with content appearing on each row.  I would write out the content as standard HTML using

```
var description = '<table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>';
```

and then pass this and other values such as subject through the following function to encode it for passing in XML -

```
xmlEncode = function(strInput) {
    var c;
    var xmlEncode = '';

    if (strInput == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (strInput == '') {
        return '';
    }

    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < strInput.length; cnt++) {
        c = strInput.charCodeAt(cnt);

        if (((c > 96) && (c < 123)) ||
            ((c > 64) && (c < 91)) ||
            (c == 32) ||
            ((c > 47) && (c < 58)) ||
            (c == 46) ||
            (c == 44) ||
            (c == 45) ||
            (c == 95)) {
            xmlEncode = xmlEncode + String.fromCharCode(c);
        } else {
            xmlEncode = xmlEncode + '&#' + c + ';';
        }
    }

    return xmlEncode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach that may be easier to implement is:

1. Create an on demand workflow that creates an email. This will allow you to easily edit and maintain the template, e.g. if you want to change the wording of the email you wont have to recode.
2. Start the workflow from JavaScript.

This will effectively achieve the same as creating the entire email in JavaScript but is probably easier to implement.